# Jetpack Compose: Firing onClick events using a remote control in Android TV

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I'm building my Android TV app using Jetpack Compose, and I'm trying to fire some `onClick` events on some *Text* components.

I've implemented the `Modifier.focusable`, so it can be focused using the remote control, and I've implemented `Modifier.clickable` to be launched when, well, the component is clicked.

However, when I launch the app on an emulator, I can focus and select the component properly, as I can see the change on the background color, but I can't fire the event inside `Modifier.clickable` when pressing on the OK button on my remote control (in my case it's `KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER`). The event is fired if I click with the mouse inside the emulator, however.

Here is my code

```
   @Composable
   fun FocusablePill(text: String, focusRequester: FocusRequester = FocusRequester()) {

        val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        val isFocused by interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()
        val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
        val color = if (isFocused || isPressed) action else lightTranslucent_10
        val shape = RoundedCornerShape(CornerSize(24.dp))

        Text(
            text = text,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.button,
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .focusable(
                    interactionSource = interactionSource
                )
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = null //this is just cosmetic, setting LocalIndication.current still doesn't work
                ) {
                    onCommandEntered(text)
                }
                .background(color, shape)
                .padding(16.dp, 8.dp)
        )
    }
```

I've also tried with `Modifier.selectable`, but the result is the same. Event is only fired on mouse click. Also, using *Button* components doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipDukhov, but in this case, the problem is on the onClick event. The focus works fine.

Comment: Try using the `onKeyEvent` modifier and see if it gives you any event when you press a remote control key. Perhaps it is perceived as a keyboard and not a mouse. If so, you probably need to [report it] (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128).

Comment: Hi @PhilipDukhov 
I added onKeyEvent and now I can check on (it.type == KeyUp && it.key == Key.DirectionCenter) so I can perform whatever I need, but still I find this as a workaround. I believe that, because I'm running on Android TV but inside a ComposeActivity, rather than a "leanback friendly" Fragment, the button clicks are not being handled properly. However, navigation is.

Comment: I agree that this is a workaround, [let compose maintainers know](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) what behavior you expect.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov done. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202171423

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, this was fixed and should be working as of 1.1.0-beta01. Both the Dpad center and the enter key will trigger a click on the focused view now. If you want to handle other keys (e.g., a game controller), you can use Modifier.onKeyEvent.

Comment: Confirmed! Although jetpack compose’s accessibility support could still use a lot more help!